# AngularJS 1.3 - Error: error:modulerr Module Error (using ng-view, $routeProvider)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm going through a tutorial that's using AngularJS 1.0 and I'm using 1.3.8. I've come across a issue that I can't figure out what the problem is.

The error I am getting is:

`Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=contacts&p1=Error%3…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A350)`

I believe it's deprecated code from the tutorial to the 1.3.8 version of AngularJS.

Can someone point out what's wrong with the code?

contacts.js

```
angular.module('contacts', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    // Configure the routes
    $routeProvider
        .when('/contact/:index', {
            // Edit contact
            templateUrl: 'edit.html',
            controller: 'Edit'
        })
        .when('/', {
            // List all contacts
            templateUrl: 'list.html'
        });
}])
.controller('Contacts', ['$scope', function($scope){
    // Contacts is the parent controller, so  $scope.contacts is available to all children
    $scope.contacts= [
        { name: 'Tom',  number: '2345678888' },
        { name: 'Abe',  number: '4338995647' },
        { name: 'John', number: '9892668178' }
    ];
}])
.controller('Edit', ['$scope', function($scope, $routeParams){
    // Load in a contact from the route (/contact/:$index)
    $scope.contact = $scope.contacts[$routeParams.index];
    $scope.index = $routeParams.index;
}]);
```

index.html

```
<html ng-app="contacts">
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Contacts</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width">

<style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
        font: 14px/1.5 sans-serif;
        color: #222;
        margin: 3em;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="Contacts">
<h1>Contacts</h1>
<div ng-view></div>
</div>

<script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js "></script>
<script src="contacts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

edit.html

```
<h2>Edit</h2>
<ul>
    <li>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" ng-model="contact.name">
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="number">Number:</label>
        <input type="text" id="number" ng-model="contact.number">
    </li>
</ul>

<a href="/AngularJS/index.html">Back to the list</a>
```

list.html

```
<h2>List</h2>
<div>
    <label for="search">Search:</label>
        <input type="search" ng-model="search">
</div>

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:search">
         <a href="#/contact/{{ $index }}">{{ contact.name }}</a>
        : {{ contact.number }}
    </li>
</ul>
<a href="/AngularJS/index.html">Back to the list</a>
```

Comment: what pops up when you use the non-minified version of angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to include angular-route script as well after angularjs inorder to use `ngRoute`

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-route.min.js
```

Older version of angular used to have the router included in the same angularjs core script. They have moved on since 1.2.x and angular router is now opt in by including separate script.

Do:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

Also make sure dependency annotation list and the constructor argument list matches in order and in count, you are missing `$routeParams` in the list.

```
.controller('Edit', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 
             function($scope, $routeParams)
```

Comment: Just saw abother bug pointed out by the deleted answer. SInce it is removed i am adding it in my answer for the record.

Comment: Cheers, yeah I'm having issues now when clicking on a name to edit, getting a `/AngularJS/AngularJS/contact/0` not found.

Comment: Figured it out, problem with my list.hml, should be this: `<a href="#/contact/{{ $index }}">{{ contact.name }}</a>`